# Netty - can I cache those ChannelHandlerContext in Hash map and response it later?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

Here is the step of implementation and questions:

1. Netty server handler receives message from client
2. Because there are other running threads to process the user data, we need to put this request to a queue and let the worker process
3. After the worker process the data, can we response back to client in the worker thread? i.e. either using a HashMap to cache the ChannelHandlerContext and get it later from worker thread to response?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The operations provided by `ChannelHandlerContext` are all thread-safe, and thus you can keep the context instance for later use and use it from other thread.

A `ChannelHandlerContext` has the same life cycle with the `Channel` it belongs to. When the `Channel` is closed, `ChannelHandlerContext` is also dereferenced from the pipeline.  If you keep the reference to a `ChannelHandlerContext`, you should dereference it or make sure the garbage collector can reclaim it.

Comment: May i know when the context will be removed from memory? Is it when http timeout ? Besides, will it possible other request reuses the same context when I cache it in Memory ? thanks very much

Comment: Answer updated. You can of course write multiple messages from different threads with the same context object.