# Can i cache the channel from ChannelHandlerContext in a HashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

If i cache the Channel [`ctx.channel()`] instead of caching the ChannelHandlerContext  does it make any difference?

Here is the step of implementation and questions:

1. Netty server handler receives message from client
2. Because there are other running threads to process the user data, we need to put this request to a queue and let the worker process
3. We need to have the same connection used for multiple message exchange between the server and client
4. whenever a message is ready to send to client from the worker thread is it good practice to use the channel cached in the HashMap

   final ChannelFuture status = channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(payload.getBytes()));
5. And whenever worker thread wants to close the connection with the client, if we close the cached channel, Is that is sufficient?

see this [Netty - can I cache those ChannelHandlerContext in Hash map and response it later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845594/netty-can-i-cache-those-channelhandlercontext-in-hash-map-and-response-it-late).

Above one is about using the ChannelHandlerContext, but mine is about the channel. Also is there any advantage in using ChannelHandlerContext vs Channel

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can cache a `Channel` and use it later. If all you need is to `writeAndFlush()` a message from another thread later, just caching `Channel` is perfectly fine.

`ChannelHandlerContext` is useful when you want to modify the pipeline dynamically, fire events up and down the pipeline etc. If you don't need these, you can just use `Channel`.

Comment: thanks @spinlok. On close of the channel will the ChannelHandlerContext will also be available for GC?

Comment: Yes, as the linked answer says, both `ChannelHandlerContext` and `Channel` are dereferenced from the pipeline when the channel is closed. So, make sure you don't hold a reference to the `Channel` once it is closed, and it will be GC'ed